# How Can I increase the speed aka performance of solr query

Tags: performance, search, solr, lucene, search-engine

How can I increase the speed aka performance of solr query. We use this search operation for searching customer information based upon the first name and last and there should be 10 suggested result. Can anyone suggest anything regarding this? What specific tips I suppose to follow to increase speed in this scenario?

Comment: The question is impossible to answer with the current details. What have you tried? What is too slow? What is the response you're getting? What is the type of the fields you are searching? What did you expect should happen? How large is your data set? How many servers are the dataset spread across? How does it compare to other queries that are fast enough?

Comment: okay I am glad you raised the concerned question here are the infos

we are basically trying to search the customer(vehicle owner) names on the basis of first name and last name for instance if the customer name is Taylor Grey so think about every possible combination of the name starts with like Ty/tyl like this, another criteria if you type 17 digit alfanumeric*(Unique) charecters then also its gonna seach you the customer.

Comment: The queries are working fine but its need to be done some milisec faster thats we are trying to do.

About the dataset its like 70 Million(names) datas are there and for 17 digit data is around 60 million.

we are using 4 solr servers. I am providing the sample query for your help.We should provide them 10 suggestion from our search.

Comment: "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":6,
    "params":{
      "q":"(first_nm:(\"VIJ\" OR VIJ*)) OR (organization_nm:(\"VIJ\" OR VIJ*))",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "indent":"true",
      "rows":"11",
      "wt":"json",
      "lowercaseOperators":"true",
      "bq":["first_nm:VIJ*^100",
        "organization_nm:VIJ*^40"]}},

Comment: "response":{"numFound":10407,"start":0,"maxScore":116.13281,"docs":[
      {
        "customer_type":"PERSON",
        "customer_id":"6**********",
        "pr_phn_phone_no":"5***********",
        "mail_adr_postal_cd":"9***",
        "mail_adr_address_line_1":"2**** DETROIT AVE",
        "pr_eml_email_address":"******@gmail.com",
        "first_nm":"VIJ",
        "last_nm":"SUM",
        "mail_addr_state":"CA",
        "mail_addr_city":"CONCORD",
        "distributor":"US",
        "mail_adr_country_nm":"USA",
        "_version_":1******************},

Comment: sorry we are using 8 solr servers..